# Why I cannot switch to Iframe on this website?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to switch to Iframe on this link https://www.walmart.com/blocked but I cannot

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='iframe'))
```

gives error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe"}
```

Or even if I try to do

```
driver.find_elements(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value='//iframe'))
```

I get error

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//iframe" is: [object HTMLIFrameElement]. It should be an element.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `iframes` are inside a shadow-root there. [image]

Comment: is there way to access them via Python Selenium?

Comment: Sure, there are a lot of questions about it here. Personally I never had this on the work, but I saw such questions here.

Answer (score 0):

In the link which you shared, iframe tag is inside 'Shadow DOM', which is why selenium throws exception

Try with JavaScript executor to access the web element in chrome, it will work.

For more details please do refer [Handle Shadow DOM](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver)